# Program to know all the possible path from 1 to n in a graph

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I made this c program to know all paths from 1-n in a graph. This is a undirectional graph.
I want to, store in array arr[], all the paths from 1 to n, but i am unable to print them exactly (because of the way i move in the recursive function, they are printed kind of, partially)

How can i eliminate this thing?

Basically, this program is a depth first search using recursion, and i have stored the graph data in adjacency list(i have to use them, because data can be too large and cant be stored in 2d-array)

To go through all the paths. I visit all the neighbors of 1 initially. And then their neighbors (as in dfs). While i am on some path, and i visit some list through it, say list number x, i mark it 1, so that we don'd keep visit it in this path again or keep walking circularly through it. and when i am done with it, i mark it 0 again, so that if any other path uses it as sub path it can again go through it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int mark[100001]={0},n,m,sols,arr[100001],j=0,k;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* nextnode;
};
struct list
{
    struct node* head;
};
struct graph
{
    int v;
    struct list* arr;
};
struct node* createnewnode(int data){
    struct node* newnode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->nextnode=NULL;
    return newnode;
}
struct graph* createnewgraph(int v)
{
    int i;
    struct graph* newgraph=malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
    newgraph->v=v;
    newgraph->arr=malloc((v+1)*sizeof(struct list));
    for(i=0;i<=v;i++){
        newgraph->arr[i].head=NULL;
    }
    return newgraph;
}
void addedge(struct graph* g,int a,int b)
{
    struct node* newnode=createnewnode(b);
    newnode->nextnode=g->arr[a].head;
    g->arr[a].head=newnode;
    newnode=createnewnode(a);
    newnode->nextnode=g->arr[b].head;
    g->arr[b].head=newnode;
}
void dfs(struct graph* g,int listnum)
{
   struct node* al;
   al=g->arr[listnum].head;
   mark[listnum]=1;
   arr[j++]=listnum;
   while(al!=NULL){
        if(mark[al->data]==1){
            al=al->nextnode;
            continue;
        }
        if(al->data==n){
            arr[j++]=n;
            for(k=0;k<j;k++)
                 printf("%d ",arr[k]);
            printf("\n");
            sols++;
        }
        else{
            dfs(g,al->data);
            mark[al->data]=0;
        }
        al=al->nextnode;
   }
}
int main()
{
    int a,b,i;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    i=0;
    struct graph* g=createnewgraph(n+1);
    while(i<m){
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        addedge(g,a,b);
        i++;
    }
    sols=0;
    dfs(g,1);
    printf("total number of paths is %d\n",sols);
    return 0;
}
```

for input : 7 7 1 2  3 2 3 4 7 4 6 2 5 6 7 5

actual paths are: 1 2 6 5 7 and 1 2 3 4 7

but what i am able to print is:

1 2 6 5 7

1 2 6 5 7 3 4 7

(notice, the 1 2 x x x 3 4 7 is the real path, but x x x, i.e. 2 6 5 of the previous path is still displayed).
How can i eliminate this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dfs function, you need to remove the current node from `arr` when your return from it. That is, you need to add `j--` at the end of dfs function and after printing the path.

Answer (score 1):

Just use another array to keep track of which nodes are already visited, here is a simple `C++` implementation,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int n, m, a, b;
vector < vector <int> > adj;
vector <int> visited, path;

void dfs(int curr) {
    if(visited[curr]) {
        return;
    }

    if(curr == n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
            cout << path[i] << ' ';
        }
        cout << n << '\n';
        return;
    }

    path.push_back(curr);
    visited[curr] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < adj[curr].size(); ++i) {
        dfs(adj[curr][i]);
    }
    path.pop_back();
    visited[curr] = false;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cin >> n >> m;

    adj = vector < vector <int> > (n+1);
    visited = vector <int> (n+1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        cin >> a >> b;
        adj[a].push_back(b);
        adj[b].push_back(a);
    }

    dfs(1);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 7
1 2 6 5 7
```